# Object does not cast shadow

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

In my scene I have a person imported for makeHuman software. A camera installed in the ceiling [0,0,2.5m] and oriented to view the floor (parallel to z axis) and a point light source installed in [2m,2m,2.5m]. In the the light source configuration, i check the **Ray shadow option**. When i render, the person does not cast shadow. I change the light source location but it does not change the situation!
[image]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot or the blend?

Comment: @NaioaiStudios, I edited my question

Comment: Is there a floor to receive the shadows? I can't see it on your screenshot...

Comment: Do you have anything under the character(like a plane or something)? The shadow needs to hit something to be seen.

Comment: @Polosson, no I did not added a floor. It seems my error

Comment: @Polosson, it is my error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved in comments:

A shadow needs to hit something, in order to be seen. Add a plane or another object where you expect the shadow to be seen.